# handling million of rows for lookup operation using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, bigdata, dask

I am new to data handling . I need to create python program to search a record from a samplefile1 in samplefile2. i am able to achieve it but for each record out of 200 rows in samplefile1 is looped over 200 rows in samplefile2 , it took 180 seconds complete execution time.

I am looking for something to be more time efficient so that i can do this task in minimum time .

My actual Dataset size is : 9million -> samplefile1 and 9million --> samplefile2.

Here is my code using Pandas.

sample1file1 rows:

```
number='7777777777' subscriber-id="7777777777" rrid=0 NAPTR {order=10 preference=50 flags="U"service="sip+e2u"regexp="!^(.*)$!sip:+7777777777@ims.mnc001.mcc470.3gppnetwork.org;user=phone!"replacement=[]};
number='7777777778' subscriber-id="7777777778" rrid=0 NAPTR {order=10 preference=50 flags="U"service="sip+e2u"regexp="!^(.*)$!sip:+7777777778@ims.mnc001.mcc470.3gppnetwork.org;user=phone!"replacement=[]};
number='7777777779' subscriber-id="7777777779" rrid=0 NAPTR {order=10 preference=50 flags="U"service="sip+e2u"regexp="!^(.*)$!sip:+7777777779@ims.mnc001.mcc470.3gppnetwork.org;user=phone!"replacement=[]};
.........100 rows
```

samplefile2 rows

```
number='7777777777' subscriber-id="7777777777" rrid=0 NAPTR {order=10 preference=50 flags="U"service="sip+e2u"regexp="!^(.*)$!sip:+7777777777@ims.mnc001.mcc470.3gppnetwork.org;user=phone!"replacement=[]};
number='7777777778' subscriber-id="7777777778" rrid=0 NAPTR {order=10 preference=50 flags="U"service="sip+e2u"regexp="!^(.*)$!sip:+7777777778@ims.mnc001.mcc470.3gppnetwork.org;user=phone!"replacement=[]};
number='7777777769' subscriber-id="7777777779" rrid=0 NAPTR {order=10 preference=50 flags="U"service="sip+e2u"regexp="!^(.*)$!sip:+7777777779@ims.mnc001.mcc470.3gppnetwork.org;user=phone!"replacement=[]};
........100 rows
```

```
import time
import pandas as pd

def timeit(func):
    """
    Decorator for measuring function's running time.
    """
    def measure_time(*args, **kw):
        start_time = time.time()
        result = func(*args, **kw)
        print("Processing time of %s(): %.2f seconds."
              % (func.__qualname__, time.time() - start_time))
        return result

    return measure_time

@timeit
def func():
    df = pd.read_csv("sample_2.txt", names=["A1"], skiprows=0, sep=';')
    df.drop(df.filter(regex="Unname"),axis=1, inplace=True)
    finaldatafile1=df.fillna("TrackRow")
    
    df1=pd.read_csv("sample_1.txt",names=["A1"],skiprows=0,sep=';')
    df1.drop(df.filter(regex="Unname"),axis=1, inplace=True)
    finaldatafile2=df1.fillna("TrackRow")
    indexdf=df.index
    indexdf1=df1.index
    ##### for loop for string to be matched (small datasets#######
    for i in range(0,len(indexdf)-1):
        lookup_value=finaldatafile1.iloc[[i]].to_string()
       # print(lookup_value)
    ######### for loop for lookup dataset( large dataset #########
        for j in range(0,len(indexdf1)-1):
            match_value=finaldatafile2.iloc[[j]].to_string()
            if i is j:
                print (f"Its a match on lookup table position {j} and for string {lookup_value}")
            else:
                print("no match found in complete dataset")
if __name__ == "__main__":
      func()
```

Comment: Could you improve your sample so we have a few rows from both `sample_1.txt` and `sample_2.txt` to allow the script to be tested

Comment: @MartinEvans , my sample data is customer specific i have shared three rows for each file . but you increase them till 100 as data consist all most same data except few values like subcriberid.

Comment: @MartinEvans , any suggestions or code to achieve this? Your help will be very helpful

Comment: Maybe you can try doing an [inner `join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)?

Comment: @pavithraes can u guide more on that to try. However answer from Martin solved it but lets see for another method as i could have more use cases as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think using Pandas is helping here as you are just comparing whole lines. An alternative approach would be to load the first file as a set of lines. Then enumerate over the lines in the second file testing if it is in the set. This will be much faster:

```
@timeit
def func():
    with open('sample_1.txt') as f_sample1:
        data1 = set(f_sample1.read().splitlines())
    
    with open('sample_2.txt') as f_sample2:
        data2 = f_sample2.read().splitlines()
        
    for index, entry in enumerate(data2):
        if entry in data1:
            print(f"It's a match on lookup table position {index} and for string\n{entry}")
        else:
            print("no match found in complete dataset")
```

Comment: ok let me try this will share the results with time and processing power

Comment: thank you for this hint i m able to achieve it. Just one query , is there any limit for set array for storing values?

Comment: I'm guessing just the amount of memory you have. If that is a problem an alternative would be to hash each line and store that instead in the set